# Thunderbird extension: add button in message reader toolbar

Tags: xul, thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I'm trying to add a button in the message reader toolbar : [image]

I successfully added a button in the mail toolbar, using the chrome.manifest and XUL files. I just don't know how to access this particular toolbar. I have tried finiding it using the DOM Inspector, to no avail.
My button doesn't appear in the "Customize" box either.

My question is therefore: how can I add a button to this particular toolbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking some more with the DOM Inspector I finally got it.

The toolbar and toolbox ids are `header-view-toolbar` and `header-view toolbox` and the classes are `inline-toolbar` and `inline-toolbox`. The CSS class for buttons is `msgHeaderView-button`. The XUL for adding a button there should look like this:

```
<toolbarpalette id="header-view-toolbar">
  <toolbarbutton id="my-button"/>
</toolbarpalette>

<toolbarbutton id="my-button"
  label="This is my button!"
  tooltiptext="Click on it!"
  oncommand="MyButton[1]()"
  class="toolbarbutton-1 msgHeaderView-button my-button"
/>
```

Comment: Nice answer. Thanks for coming back to follow up and post a detailed, self-answer. This is truly how you give back! https://twitter.com/jmort253/status/443390016912236544. The Mozilla DOM is one of the most time consuming things to work through, so I'm sure this will help others.